# How to return Inserted Updated Id in a Merge query

Tags: c#, linq, linq2db

I have 2 tables in my database:

Table `dbo.Customers`:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Customer1 |
| 2 | Customer2 |

Table `dbo.Images`

| Id | OwnerId | ImageUrl | OwnerType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | abc.jpg | Info |
| 2 | 10 | xyx.jpg | Products |
| 3 | 1 | customer1.jpg | Customer |
| 4 | 2 | customer2.jpg | Customer |

Here Pk 3 and 4 have the `OwnerTypeId` that matches the `Customer` table.

`OwnerId` basically has a FK relationship with the `Customer` table and `Ownertype` is the name of the table.

What I want to do is

- Update `Images` table if the record exist
- Otherwise create a new record

What I have done so far:

I use a `Merge` query to update the record if exist otherwise create the new record in the `Image` table

```
public Task<int> GetInsertedUpdatedId(int customerId, string ImageUrl, Cancellationtoken cancellationToken)
{
    await db.Images
            .Merge()
            .Using(new[] { new { OwnerId = customerId} })
                 .On((_new, old) => _new.OwnerId == old.OwnerId)
                 .UpdateWhenMatched((old, _new) => new Image
                     {
                          ImageUrl = Image.ImageUrl,                                                
                          UpdatedAt = Sql.CurrentTimestampUtc
                     })
                 .InsertWhenNotMatched(_new => new Image
                     {
                          OwnerId = _new.OwnerId,
                          OwnerType = ImageOwnerType.Customer,                                                
                          CreatedAt = Sql.CurrentTimestampUtc,
                          UpdatedAt = Sql.CurrentTimestampUtc,
                     })              
            .MergeAsync(cancellationToken);
 
    int insertedOrUpdatedId = await db.Images
                 .Where(x => x.OwnerId == customerId)
                 .Select(x => x.Id)
                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

What I want:

- I want to find a way to return inserted/updated Id without making another database call to get `insertedUpdatedId` after the merge is completed.

Is there a way to do it in the merge query and return Inserted/Updated Id ?

Thank you for having a look
.

Comment: The Q in Linq is for QUERY and it is not intended  to be used for INSERT nor UPDATE.

Comment: Thank you. I did change the header as per your suggestion

Comment: Is it linq2db? Add tag.

Comment: it returns count as how many records updated/inserted. i would suggest to have a stored proc where you can do select output to table or get a new record id

Comment: Use `MergeWithOutputAsync`.